# not able to get the div's updated innerhtml on view source

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am rendering my div with a javascript from the server side code.
The script when rendered on clitn makes another call asyncnronously and gets some data (an image) to be displayed ,depending upon the parametrs sent. However, when i try to see the page's source , i don't get the "image tag" in it, but when i see it through firebug or IE developer tool bar, i get to see the image..
When I am trying to get the image object thru javascript, it doesnt return anything.

Pls let me know how should i get an indication whether the image has been rendered on client or not??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you view source in a browser, you get to see the source code as it was received.  Anything that modifies it in the page is not shown.  You can see changes to the HTML/DOM by viewing the code in one of the browser dev toolbars like the IE Dev toolbar, the developer toolbar in Chrome/Safari, or Firebug.

To find out if an image has rendered I believe you can bind the load event of the image to tell your code that it was indeed loaded.  JQuery's .load() event is something I have used for this in the past, but there are caveats, see http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Answer (score 1):

view source in context menu shows you the HTML code as sent by the server. If you want to see the actual HTML, serialisation you can:

- select the part in your page and use "view selection source" (in FF, not sure of the name)
- use Firebug "inspect Element".
- use a script like: document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML;

but to know whether an image has been loaded or not, you should use a load event handler like:

```
<img src="there.jpg" onload="triggeredCode()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will know it, if it is correctly displayed after page load...